# How to setup event registration and paypal payment?

Tags: 7, commerce, payment-gateways

We have events and we take registrations for them. [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module is installed for that purpose and it's working great. Now, since those events are paid events, we want to implement *PayPal payment* method as well.

The problem is we need to **combine** the registration process and the paypal payment into one process. That said, user should click the button *Register & pay* and that should do 2 things:

1. Register the user for the event (this is already working as a part of [Entity Reg](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module)
2. Redirect the user to *PayPal payment gateway*

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: I want to do the exact same thing.  Antonio, have you found an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Registration Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_commerce) module. This module acts as a integration point between entity registration and drupal commerce enabling you to implement paid registration using entity register. Also use [Commerce paypal](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) for paypal integration with drupal commerce.

Comment: Commerce is a huge module, and is not something that should be thrown onto a Drupal site just to get a better registration workflow. If you already have a commerce platform then this recommendation is fine, but the OP says they are already using Entity Registration instead.

Answer (score -1):

I think the [Commerce Paypal IPN Rules integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal_ipn_rules_integration) module should fit your requirements. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... comes to give modular capabilities for Paypal IPN handling.
>
> Combined with Drupal Commerce, Rules and the Paypal payment method, using this module you will be able to change your site workflow and logic.
>
> As an example, while the "Commerce subscription products PayPal" integrates with the IPN to start/stop user subscription, but depends on specific user fields and content types, in this module you will be able to achieve the same, but for your own selected fields, content types, etc.